# В чем отличия PHP_SELF от SCRIPT_NAME ?

Tags: php

У меня они двое выдают `"/param/index.php"`

Я думал если PHP_SELF выдает путь от DOCUMENT_ROOT то сдесь все логично....
Но от SCRIPT_NAME я ожидал index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SCRIPT_NAME это то что исполняется(точка входа с точки зрения сервера), а PHP_SELF это то что было вызвано (точка входа с точки зрения клиента)

сравните вывод в обоих случаях:

http://site/file.php/test

Comment: Я правильно пониманию что между ними различия будут при формировании ЧПУ ?

Comment: по идее да, но я не помню, просто считайте PHP_SELF чем-то внешним, а SCRIPT_NAME именем своего скрипта.